# Accessing an Non Numerical Index in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

In the image above, I have used groupby to arrange the dataset by its Genre. I want to extract the Genre in which maximum movies were released (as shown by the blue line in the image). How can I access the figure of 177 and print it out as output?

Comment: Use `df.loc['Comedy','Movie']`

Comment: It is returning a KeyError  'Comedy'.

Comment: What is `print (df.index.tolist())` ?

Comment: Jezrael, I am sorry but I couldn't find the solution even in the suggestion you provided.

Comment: What is `print (df.index.tolist())` ?

Comment: print (df.index.tolist()) where are you reading this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198073/discussion-between-jezrael-and-hammeroflight).